# Possible orphans in cataloginventory_stock_item?

Tags: products, inventory, cataloginventory

Should every record in cataloginventory_stock_item link to a record in catalog_product_entity?  When I run the following SQL I get 15,874 products in cataloginventory_stock_item that do not match a record in catalog_product_entity.

```
select count(*) from cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked in magento version 1.7 and it is definitely true there (that orphans should *not* exist in `cataloginventory_stock_item`).

The `cataloginventory_stock_item` table's `product_id` column has a foreign key referencing `catalog_product_entity.entity_id`, with "ON DELETE CASCADE, ON UPDATE CASCADE" options set. That means that deleting products from `catalog_product_entity` would automatically delete those from `cataloginventory_stock_item`.

You would not be able to add records to `cataloginventory_stock_item` unless they existed in the parent table. You might be using an older version of magento, or, more likely, you may have made a mistake in copying the database and lost some foreign keys that you should have there.

Comment: I've seen this nonsense where people installed Magento and managed to change a table to MYISAM or deleted a foreign key association to "fix" a problem from bad advice given through the various Magento forums. Get a dba to help you if you're having FK issues, the easy fix becomes the awful table bloat fix later in Magento's life. One bright light back in the 1.4 days told people how to remove all the foreign key associations to make MySQL more dependable like using only MYISAM tables... Cough, cough, flat tables with transactional rollback, ahem.

Comment: I think one of our devs deleted a bunch of keys when we were on 1.4 and somehow everything stayed afloat until we tried to upgrade. Agreed, definitely don't mess with the database structure or data unless you understand it very well.